# Site content and structure - different icons for team subsites

Tags: content-and-structure

I have just found out that when I check the site content and structure in site setting, there are two different icons for the same type of subsites. First thing that crossed my mind was that there are some sites functions activated and therefore the icon is different but it is not the reason as the activated functions are identical.

[image]

Does anybody know where the difference is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the first icon (tree) indicates a Publishing site, the Sharepoint 2013 icon indicates any other type of site (Team, Community, Project etc).

You can check the site features of the site that does not have the Sharepoint 2013 icon, under **Site Actions** --> **Manage Site Features** --> **Sharepoint Server Publishing** should be activated.